# Preserve Msg Unit of Order Property from Source ActiveMQ to Weblogic Queue via Bridge

Tags: jms, weblogic, activemq-classic, messaging, bridge

I need to maintain message processing order from an ActiveMQ to Weblogic Queue via Bridge.

I tried setting `JMS_BEA_UnitOfOrder` property from source and enabled `Preserve Msg Property` in the bridge configuration. However, I still could not see this property when message in coming in destination Queue. Need suggestion on this.

Bridge Config below:

[image: bridge config]

Comment: Added Screenshot in the query for configuration

Comment: How do you know the messages are getting out of order?

Comment: I have multiple consumers for the same queue, hence ordering is not there. With Unit of Order JMS maintains the order, but issue here is this property is getting passed from ActiveMq queue but when received at WebLogic Queue via JMS, I am not able to see this property, even with Preserve Msg Property of the bridge set as true.

Comment: Retrieving Queue Property using msg.getStringProperty("JMS_BEA_UnitOfOrder")

Comment: Have you confirmed that the `JMS_BEA_UnitOfOrder` property exists on the message(s) before they cross the bridge? If so, how?

Comment: I have checked the property from Source it is present there from the logs which contains all custom and header properties, post coming in Queue I checked property disappeared